# How to update the configuration.php file in Joomla 3 for a subdomain

Tags: php, joomla

I created a dummy website, with dummy articles in Latin. When I click on the read more links
the article pages open completely un-formatted. I read that it has something to do with the live_site variable in the configuration.php file. I've tried physically assigning the whole URL, but that just un-formats the home page too. I've also noticed that clicking the read more link brings me to the top URL, but physically entering the bottom URL shows the page formatted correctly.

http://corba.co.nf/index.php/art-lectures/73-hideous-still-lifes

http://corba.co.nf/corba/index.php/art-lectures/73-hideous-still-lifes

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Because your site is installed into a sub directory.

Comment: I know that, but how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Move the site or use `.htaccess` code to handle requests for your site from a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

- Rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess
- Replace this line

  ```
  RewriteBase /
  ```

with this one

```
    RewriteBase /corba
```